# Calculate overlap efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapely, cartopy

In my code I would like to calculate the overlap between multiple polygons and another polygon. As an example, I made the following three polygons ('tracks') and a square polygon. I need to calculate the overlay of the tracks with the square.
First, the polygons:

```
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from shapely import geometry
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

#Set up polygons
square = geometry.Polygon([(-3,-3),(3,-3),(3,3),(-3,3),(-3,-3)]) #blue square
track1 = geometry.Polygon([(-6,-0.5),(6,-0.5),(6,0.5),(-6,0.5),(-6,-0.5)]) 
#green track 1
track2 = geometry.Polygon([(-0.5,-6),(-0.5,6),(-2,6),(-2,-6),(-0.5,-6)]) #red 
track 2
track3 = geometry.Polygon([(-8.5,-3),(-7.5,-3),(8.5,4),(7.5,4),(-8.5,-3)]) 
#yellow track 3
```

Which looks like this when plotted:
[image]

Now, to get the overlay, I first combine the three tracks using `cascaded_union` into an polygon. After that, I get the intersect polygon:

```
casc = cascaded_union([track1,track2,track3]) #ISSUE 1
intersect = square.intersection(casc) #ISSUE 2
```

Then, to get the overlap, I use:

```
ratio = intersect.area/square.area*100.0
print(ratio)
```

Which yields a value of `41.98598710317461`. So the overlap is approximately 42%.

The issue is that I have to calculate the overlap hundreds of times. The geometries only have to be made once, but I know (from using `time.time()`) the two lines (indicated by ISSUE 1 and ISSUE 2) take up the major part of the running time. Is there any faster way to calculate the overlap?